# Navbar with dynamic content and behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Say I have the following `App.js`:

**App.js**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Router>
          <Home path="/" />
          <RouteA path="/routeA" />
          <RouteB path="/routeB" /> 
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

So I need the `<Navbar />` to behave and look differently in the `/routeA` and `/routeB`.

For example, there is a back button in the `<Navbar />`. And when user is in `/routeA`, clicking the back btn will go back one step in history.

However, when user is in `/routeB`, not only that clicking back btn will now pops up an alert, we also need to render a component that has updating props inside the `<Navbar />`.

So the way I go about this is, well, `redux`: The `<Navbar />` is connected to its own slice of state in the store. Then, in my routes, in order to make the navbar dynamic accordingly, I dispatch actions with my `function` and `component` to make the `<Navbar />` behave and look the way I want. So far so good.

Problem is we can't serialize 'function' and 'component' objects in the store and subsequently localstorage...so like on refresh, they are gone...

So my workaround for the 'function' is I immediately dispatch it in the routes' constructor. Whereas for the 'component', I use `Portal` in my routes' `render` method to insert it to my `<Navbar />`...

My question is how would you implement this differently?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Hum... Could you perhaps use the current URL or current route to decide what the function does since it is dependant on that? So basically you could have a chain of `ifs` or a `switch` and just call the proper function accordingly.
I am not sure if that is the best practice, but it would be a solution for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can send function to route components and call this funciton when component is mounted, you can have functions defined inside NavBar component, and switch based on the page you are on.

```
updateLayout = (page) => {this.setState({currentPage: page})}
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Navbar currentPage={this.state.currentPage} />
    <Router>
      <Home path="/" render={()=> <ComponentHome updateLayout={this.updateLayout}>} />
      <RouteA path="/routeA" render={()=> <ComponentA updateLayout={this.updateLayout}>} />
      <RouteB path="/routeB" render={()=> <ComponentB updateLayout={this.updateLayout}>} /> 
    </Router>
  </div>
);
```

}

Comment: Thanks. But the dynamic methods for the `<Navbar />` might come from the route components cuz they need access to their props or setState. The same goes to the dynamic components for the `<Navbar />` too; they will have props being controlled inside the route components...